# CSS/Mobile div background image not showing up immediately

Tags: html, css

I have a background image on a big div below the fold... when I load the page on my iPhone and I scroll down, the image shows up only after I scroll past the top edge of the div (a small delay essentially)...
It does happen only mobile.
I'm wondering if it's because the photos are too heavy or else...

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Make the image dimensions smaller, increase the JPEG compression, or both.

Answer (score 2):

Your image has a very big size.

You have to make image size smaller and load it only for tablets/mobiles.

CSS code will be like this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) { .mydiv { background-image: url('images_folder/smaller_image.jpg')}}
```